# Angular import cost

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

I'm working on an angular project. I'm trying to reduce the bundle size, so I'm using [VS Code Import Cost extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost) to check the weight that implies each 3rd party library (such as Lodash or RxJS) import.

Following best practices I'm changing imports from:
[image]

To:

[image]

As shown in the screenshots, specific imports seems to weight more than generic ones.

How is this possible? Is this because I didn't complete the change in all the files?

Versions:

- Angular 9
- Lodash 4
- RxJS 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this extension works well, but do not use specific imports. RxJS was rewritten to work well with es6 module and tree-shaking.

You can use `webpack-bundle-analyzer` and `source-map-explorer` to see the details of your bundle.

As for `lodash`, use `lodash-es` which works better with tree-shaking

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!! Will try also the analyzers :)